# How can I convert this to class-based Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

I need help converting to class-based Javascript. Below is my code:

```
function Foo(options) {
this.index = options.index;
this.name = options.name || 'foo';
var items = options.items;
var self = this;
function bar() {
    self.say();
}
items.forEach(function () {
    self.say();
});
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    bar();
}
}

Foo.prototype.say = function () {
    console.log(arguments);
};
```

This is what I have tried:

```
class Foo {
constructor(options) {
    this.index = options.index;
    this.name = options.name || 'foo';
    this.items = options.items

    this.items.forEach(() => {
        this.say()
    })
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        this.bar();
    }
}
bar() {
    this.say();
}

}

class say extends Foo {
    constructor() {
       console.log(arguments)
    }

}
```

I am currently trying to see how class based Javascript works and to see if it is worth switching to.

Please, what could be wrong with this code?

Comment: your `class` implementation doesn't define what `say()` is

Comment: ok his post was deleted, here again the other link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/classes

Comment: you need to call `super()` inside the constructor for the child class.

Comment: Sometimes a function is just a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Foo {
   constructor(options) {
      this.index = options.index
      this.name = options.name
      this.items = options.items

      var self = this

      this.items.forEach((e) => self.say(e))

      for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i ++) {
           this.bar(items[i])
      }
   }

   say(arg) { console.log(arg)  }
   bar(arg) { this.say(arg)     }
}
```

Assuming that items is an array

Comment: Have you actually tried it, @messerbill?  I have and I can confirm that say is in the prototype for Foo

Comment: No biggie, @messerbill, it was news to me too :D

Comment: When you downvoted the answer, I just started thinking what was wrong in this 

Answer (score 1):

The class `class Foo` is mostly ok. But, you shouldn't define `class say`. It has to be a member function within `Foo`

Comment: @Liam: can you please tell me whose comment I have copied?

Comment: i didn't vote on this, but it's absolutely right. it's calling `this.say` while `this` doesn't have a `say` method.